# Double subscript with a hat

Tags: math-mode, equations, errors, subscripts, compilation-error

Hope you are doing well.

I am having some issues with double subscripts and use of hat command.

Basically I want to achieve something like this:

```
{{\hat{Y}}_r}_i^t
```

[image: had and double subscript]

But I get the "Double subscript" error. If I take off the \hat{} and do `{Y_r}_i^t` there is no error. I can also put the r inside `\hat` like `{\hat{Y_r}}_i^t`, that works, but it is not what I want

I don't really understand why the hat with subscript causes this issue, or how to circumvent it.
I am using overleaf.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This came up just recently,(somewhere) it's a result of the way the basic tex code unwinds atoms that just have a single character in their base. If you add a `{}` (or anything, more or less) you get the expected behaviour.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

${\hat{Y}_r{}}_i^t$
\end{document}
```

Comment: @campa ah thanks I'll  close  this one as dup.